# Mongoose Statc 'this' Is Undefined

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

this is my code :

```
beatSchema.statics.getBeats = async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        if (req.tags) {
            return this.where('tags').in(req.tags).exec()
        }

        return this.find().exec()
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
}
```

I Am getting this error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')'

when I call the function via an express route

When I call the function via an express route

router.route('/').get(Beat.getBeats).post(addNewBeat)
what did I get wrong?

I tried call Beat.getBeats and get the same reasults as
Beat.find() when I call it with no arguments

Comment: `router.route('/').get(Beat.getBeats)` -> `router.route('/').get((req, res, next) => Beat.getBeats(req, res, next))` See also: [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)